# OpenCart customer custom fields in order emails

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I've spent some time now trying to find an extension or some code examples that match exactly what I need, looking through similar posts on here nothing quite does what I want - so the question.

I am using Open Cart 2.0.3.1 I have created some custom customer fields which appear during the checkout stages, both billing and shipping. What I want is to get those fields to appear in the order confirmation emails that go to both the customer and the business. Can anyone point me in the direction of some code examples or plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can add fields to confirmation email in catalog/model/checkout/order, find

`public function addOrderHistory($order_id, $order_status_id, $comment = '', $notify = false) {`

Get your fields from DB, where you stored them(in customers table or in order, etc...) add before

`if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/mail/order.tpl')) {`

into $data array, ex. `$data['custom_field'] = 'some data';`
Then in your template/mail/order.tpl you can print field `<?=$custom_field?>`

Comment: in the model/checkout/order.php file it is referencing $custom_fields, then there is this `foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
          if (isset($order_info['payment_custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])){
            $format = str_replace('{custom_field_' . $custom_field['custom_field_id'] . '}', $order_info['payment_custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], $format);
          }
        }` loop but that doesnt appear to feature in the email being generated

Comment: Is your  `$order_info['payment_custom_field']` included on '/template/mail/order.tpl' ?